# Understanding mono- vs. polymorphic Core expressions

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'd like to understand how simple arithmetic expressions are compiled into GHC 9.0.1 Core

For this purpose, I've isolated the same declaration,

```
f = \x y -> sqrt x + y
```

and compiled it at two different types:

```
f :: Double -> Double -> Double

f :: Floating a => a -> a -> a
```

resulting in these very different beasts :

```
\ (x [Dmd=<S,1*U(U)>] :: Double) (y [Dmd=<S,1*U(U)>] :: Double) ->
  case x of { D# x ->
  case y of { D# y -> D# (+## (sqrtDouble# x) y) }
  }
```

in the monomorphic case and

```
\ (@a)
  ($dFloating_a22t [Dmd=<S(S(S(C(C(S))LLLLLL)LLL)LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL),U(1*U(1*U(1*C1(C1(U)),A,A,A,A,A,A),A,A,A),A,A,A,1*C1(U),A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A)>]
     :: Floating a)
  (eta_B0 :: a)
  (eta_B1 :: a) ->
  + @a
    ($p1Fractional @a ($p1Floating @a $dFloating_a22t))
    (sqrt @a $dFloating_a22t eta_B0)
    eta_B1
```

in the polymorphic one.

Besides the demand/strictness annotations (the `Dmd=...` stuff), which deserve a separate question, I'm curious to understand the different *shape* of the two resulting expressions. In the monomorphic case, we do a nested case match, but in the other one we only see the operators annotated with type variables (`@a`) and constraints (`$p1Fractional` etc.)

I guess I should add that the above output is obtained via a custom plugin pass that runs at the very end of the preexisting CoreToDo list, so after desugaring etc. (that's about all I know about this subject btw)

Is there a GHC stage in which these two compiled versions are structurally identical?

Comment: A custom plugin pass is definitely going to make this question hard to answer. I suggest you compile a debugging build of GHC. That will give you much more detailed staging in `-dverbose-core2core`, including the really unoptimized desugaring.

Comment: As for why the monomorphic version has `case`, that's fundamentally because the actual operation is known, and inlined. For the polymorphic case, GHC doesn't even know if the operations are strict.

Comment: Thank you dfeuer for the pointers. The plugin doesn't touch the result, only isolates a part of it and pretty prints it, passing the ModGuts along unchanged.

Comment: In the polymorphic version, the `case` statements are "hidden" in the typeclass dictionaries (like `$dFloating_a22t`) that are received as arguments.

Comment: danidiaz could you elaborate on "hidden"? thanks!

Comment: @ocramz At the Core level, typeclasses are implemented as records-of-functions where typeclass methods are function fields. Also, dictionaries for superclasses are embedded in the dictionaries of subclasses. For example, the dictionary for `Fractional` is embedded in the dictionary for `Floating`. One of the fields of the dictionaries passed as arguments will be a function which "knows" which concrete types it wants to sum, and will internally contain code like the `cases`s and  the monomorphic `+##`.

Comment: @ocramz If I'm reading it correctly, `+ @a ($p1Fractional @a ($p1Floating @a $dFloating_a22t))` means "take the `Floating` dictionary, extract the `Fractional` dictionary from it, and then extract the implementation of `Num`'s  `+`  from it". I'm not sure why there isn't a further `$p1Num` accessor though.

Comment: @ocramz, can you share the plugin? I'd love to play with it a bit.

Comment: @pedrofurla , the plugin is not public but you can reconstruct the part I've described above from a blogpost I just wrote : http://ocramz.github.io/haskell/ghc/metaprogramming/2021/06/22/finding-core-th.html

Answer (score 4):

Internally a `Float` is a data constructor with one field containing a primitive `Float#` in the underlying machine's format (so a 32-bit word).

```
data Float = MkFloat Float#
```

This is a boxed representation so that a `Float` may also be a thunk. It is the role of a `case` expression to evaluate any thunk and then access the underlying machine `Float#`.

Hence, your function `Float -> Float -> Float`, after simplification, compiles to a function that matches on the arguments and performs primitive operations on the underlying values.

---

Type classes are compiled to dictionaries.

```
class Floating a where
  sqrt :: a -> a
  ...

-- becomes a record --

data Floating a = MkFloating {
  sqrt :: a -> a,
  ... }
```

Polymorphic functions become dictionary-passing functions

```
Floating a => a -> a -> a
-- becomes --
Floating a -> a -> a -> a
```

Method invocations become field accesses:

```
sqrt x
-- becomes --
sqrt floatingDict x

-- where floatingDict :: Floating a is constructed from dictionary parameters in scope and from instances (which are compiled to dictionaries or functions on dictionaries)
```

(NB: this is somewhat specific to GHC, other compilers, though rare, may do things differently.)

---

> Is there a GHC stage in which these two compiled versions are structurally identical?

No, why would they be?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. By "structurally identical" I just meant, having an AST that's comparable in shape (e.g.  `(+ (sqrt x) y)`  ), even though the internal methods are different. Since Core `Expr` doesn't have a Show instance, and the `Outputable` methods perform this pretty-printing, it's hard to see the resulting shape of the AST.

Answer (score 3):

The two functions:

```
f :: Double -> Double -> Double
f = \x y -> sqrt x + y

g :: Floating a => a -> a -> a
g = \x y -> sqrt x + y
```

diverge very early in the compilation process.  Using GHC 8.6.5 with `-O0`, you can can see that the term-level representations are identical after type checking (`-ddump-tc`):

```
-- ghc -ddump-tc -dsuppress-all -dsuppress-uniques -fforce-recomp -O0
g = \ x y -> sqrt x + y
f = \ x y -> sqrt x + y
```

but have already diverged after desugaring, before the "simple optimizer" pass (`-ddump-ds-preopt`):

```
-- ghc -ddump-ds-preopt -dsuppress-all -dsuppress-uniques -fforce-recomp -O0
g = \ @ a $dFloating ->
      let {
        $dFloating = $dFloating } in
      let {
        $dFractional = $p1Floating $dFloating } in
      let {
        $dNum = $p1Fractional $dFractional } in
      let {
        $dNum = $dNum } in
      \ x y -> + $dNum (sqrt $dFloating x) y

$dNum = $fNumDouble
$dFloating = $fFloatingDouble
f = \ x y -> + $dNum (sqrt $dFloating x) y
```

You can see here that both calls are dictionary-based and so very similar in internal structure, but already by the time we've desugared, the `g` function takes type and dictionary arguments that are absent from the `f` function definition, which uses global variables for the needed dictionaries.

I guess I'd call that a substantial difference in the AST.  The rest is just optimization -- specifically, optimizing the lookups in constant, known dictionaries for `f` and inlining the results.

It might also help to consider the simpler:

```
f :: Int -> Int
f x = x

g :: a -> a
g x = x
```

These, too, diverge after desugaring, and the difference persists in core through to the end of optimization:

```
-- ghc -ddump-simpl -dsuppress-all -dsuppress-uniques -fforce-recomp -O2
f = \ x -> x
g = \ @ a x -> x
```

I'd argue that these are two clearly different core functions, since `g` takes an extra type argument.  It's only after types are erased, when the Core is rewritten to the STG that the two functions "come back together" at the term level:

```
-- ghc -ddump-stg -dsuppress-all -dsuppress-uniques -fforce-recomp -O2
f = \r [x] x;
g = \r [x] x;
```

Comment: I never knew about `-ddump-ds-preopt`!